# Mysql: How to optimize this query. for faster results

Tags: mysql, sql

How to optimize this query, for faster result it tooks 80+ Seconds on 10 million rows.

su_id AND admin_id both are BTREE Indexed

```
SELECT su_id FROM members_ext WHERE admin_id = 5962789
```

both are INT Data Types, with BTREE index

cardinality of su_id is 8496470 and admin_id is 10437

Explain result

```
id  ,select_type,table  ,type,rows, Extra   
1, SIMPLE ,members_ext , ALL ,8496471 ,Using where
```

Comment: How many columns does the table have? Which storage engine? Can you share the table structure? @Syed Daniyal Asif

Comment: 20 Million is nothing to MySQL. Please share the other details also.

Comment: What is the data_type of su_id? Is it a varchar/alphanumeric?

Comment: apply indexes on admin_id column

Comment: both are INT Data Types, with BTREE index

Comment: cardinality of su_id is 8496470 and admin_id is 10437

Comment: Please share the `Explain result` of your query

Comment: id ,select_type,table ,type,rows, Extra 
1, SIMPLE ,members_ext , ALL ,8496471 ,Using where

Comment: how to check if admin_id is clustered or non-clustered ? i think there should be non-clustered column as it is non-unique

Comment: Buy a faster machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a combined key on admin_id, su_id, so the data can be fetched by index only.

Comment: to the downvoter: i'm really interested in the reason for it.

Comment: My dv. Because a composite key offers no advantage in this instance

Comment: so what to do Strawberry ?

Comment: and if we apply Index only to admin_id why it would not work ? because su_id is in select

Comment: i think because is not really an argument. If admin_idm is an clustering index, the benefit of the combined key wouldn't be great. But if not, the key would surely create cost on inserting new data, but if you select only admin_id and su_id, the key conatins all the data, so only the index(tree)-data has to be read and no data from the tablespace itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store numbers in varchars and then compare to numbers.  It won't work efficiently.

Add the quotes here:

```
SELECT su_id FROM members_ext WHERE admin_id = "5962789"
```

Then, for faster query, have `INDEX(admin_id, su_id)`

If anything in this answer is wrong, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE members_ext`.  There is something important missing.

Comment: if we apply Index only to admin_id why it would not work ? because su_id is in select

Comment: `INDEX(admin_id)` will help.  `INDEX(admin_id, su_id)` may be better.  I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to elaborate.